# Deleting folds over a range

Tags: folding, range

Working in an index with mucked up manual folds. Would like to delete folds from current line to end of file.

Have tried:

```
:.,$zd
```

and

```
:.,$df
```

So far I've just done a visual selection from current line to end of file and keyed in:

```
zD
```

to delete all folds recursively in the selection. Works, but would be nice if there was a way to enter a range instead.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`:normal`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Anormal) command to execute a normal command such as `zD` for all lines in a range.

To execute that command in all lines from the current one until the end of the file, you can use:

```
:.,$normal! zD
```

I'm using `:normal!` to ignore any mappings affecting the `zD` command and use Vim's native definition of that command. (But if you don't have any such mappings, using `:normal` is just fine.) You can also abbreviate the command to `:norm` if you like.

Comment: I’m actually surprised there’s not a fold-delete ex command. Nope, only fold, foldopen/foldclose, and folddoopen/folddoclosed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a good idea, but you can wrap it into Ex command:

```
command! -bar -range DeleteFolds execute printf("normal! %dGV%dGzD", <line1>, <line2>)
```